# Erase the duplicate values in a vector of structures in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a vector of structures in C++. The structure contains an int and two string variables. I want to erase the duplicate values in the vector. I tried using STD::UNIQUE but I know it is not the right method. Please help me with the effective way to solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what have you tried and where you have failed.

Comment: Also, there's no need to ask for an "effective" solution, since an ineffective one wouldn't be a solution at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in two steps:

1) Sort the vector using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a suitable binary predicate. The predicate sets the sorting criteria by implementing a [*strict weak ordering*](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).

2) Use something similar to the `erase-remove` idiom with [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique). `std::unique` has to be invoked with the same ordering applied to the sorting in step 1.

Example:

```
struct Foo 
{
  int a;
  std::string b, c;
};

// lexicographical comparison provides strict weak ordering
bool cmp(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs)
{
  return std::tie(lhs.a, lhs,b, lhs.c) < std::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b, rhs.c);
}

std::vector<Foo> v = ....
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);
vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp), vec.end());
```

Comment: I suspect that the OP wants to erase *all* non-unique elements, rather than keep one single element around. At least that's what I take from "I know `unique` is not the right method." (Then again, OPs saying "I know" should probably be taken with a grain of salt.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Good point. One day I will try reading the questions before typing. Not that this question provides much useful information.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really mind about the initial order then you can sort the vector and then use the unique method
You have a vector of struct so you need to define an operator<. I will post some code in a bit

Assuming that you have the following struct

```
struct myStruct
{
    int a;
    string b;
    string c;
}
```

You need to define an operator to sort your elements

```
inline bool operator <(const myStruct& lhs, const myStruct& rhs)
{
    return (  (lhs.a<rhs.a) 
        || ((lhs.a==rhs.a) && (lhs.b< rhs.b))
        || ((lhs.a==rhs.a) && (lhs.b==  rhs.b) (lhs.cb<  rhs.c)));
}
```

Then you need to sort your vector and use the unique
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/

```
vector<myStruct> vMyStruct;
vMyStruct.push_back(myStruct(1,"abc","abc"));
vMyStruct.push_back(myStruct(2,"abc","abc"));
vMyStruct.push_back(myStruct(1,"abc","abc"));
vMyStruct.push_back(myStruct(2,"def","def"));
vMyStruct.push_back(myStruct(2,"def","ghi"));
vMyStruct.push_back(myStruct(3,"def","ghi"));

std::sort (vMyStruct.begin(), vMyStruct.end());  // using default comparison:
std::vector<myStruct>::iterator it = std::unique (vMyStruct.begin(), vMyStruct.end());
```